# Agile control charts in JIRA - exclude non-working hours

Tags: jira, control-chart

I would like to exclude non working hours in my cycle time, how can I configure the Control charts to do that?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on JIRA server v7.10.1 . Control charts usually do not include working hours. There is an option to include non-working days in calculation. [image]

However, please ensure that if you are using Tempo for Timesheets, Your workload Schemes and Holiday Schemes are set according to your business hours.( Tempo --> Administration --> Workload schemes)